# Device Admin App not getting callbacks on Android M

Tags: android, performance, device-admin

I have a working device admin application that receives call backs on events such as password changed/expired/etc.

When i try working with same application on android M device, application **does not receive call backs on password change/expiring**.

Application gets callbacks on **device admin enabled/disabled** but not on events such as password changed or expired.
I have tried code and that works on devices with Android Lollipop 5.0

Has anyone tried fixing this?

**UPDATE:** We get change of password events on changing the type of password as well. System does not fire change password events on changing password without changing the type